# How to translate a control smoothly in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I use the following code to translate a control in wpf:

```
TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
Studio.RenderTransform = trans;
DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(0, final_point-initial_point, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim1);
```

However, this does just the linear translation which has the same speed all the time. I would like it to start slow, then speed up and finally to slow down again prior to its destination, like a Bezier curve effect. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the DoubleAnimation's `EasingFunction` property, e.g. to a `CubicEase` with `EasingMode` set to `EaseInOut`:

```
anim1.EasingFunction = new CubicEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
```

Comment: I did not know about EasingFunction , nice!

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` combined with a `SplineDoubleKeyFrame` like described in this article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819806.aspx